# Parallel programming dependency openacc

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, openacc

I am trying to parallelize this loops, but get some error in PGI compiler, I don't understand what's wrong

```
#pragma acc kernels
{
#pragma acc loop independent
    for (i = 0;i < k; i++)
    {
        for(;dt*j <= Ms[i+1].t;j++)
        {
            w = (j*dt - Ms[i].t)/(Ms[i+1].t-Ms[i].t);
            X[j] = Ms[i].x*(1-w)+Ms[i+1].x*w;
            Y[j] = Ms[i].y*(1-w)+Ms[i+1].y*w;
        }
    }
}
```

Error
85, Generating Multicore code
         87, #pragma acc loop gang
     89, Accelerator restriction: size of the GPU copy of Y,X is unknown
         Complex loop carried dependence of Ms->t,Ms->x,X->,Ms->y,Y-> prevents parallelization
         Loop carried reuse of Y->,X-> prevents parallelization
So what i can do to solve this dependence problem?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few issues here.  Also given the output, I'm assuming that you're compiling with "-ta=multicore,tesla" (i.e. targeting both a multicore CPU and a GPU)

First, since "j" is not initialized in the "i" loop, the starting value of "j" will depended on the ending value of "j" from the previous iteration of "i".  Hence, **the loops are not parallelizable**. By using "loop independent", you have forced parallelization on the outer loop, but you will get differing answers from running the code sequentially.  You will need to rethink your algorithm.

I would suggest making X and Y two dimensional.  With the first dimension of size "k".  The second dimension can be a jagged array (i.e. each having a differing size) with the size corresponding to the "Ms[i+1].t" value.

I wrote an example of using jagged arrays as part of my Chapter (#5) of the *Parallel Programming with OpenACC* book.  See: https://github.com/rmfarber/ParallelProgrammingWithOpenACC/blob/master/Chapter05/jagged_array.c

Alternatively, you might be able to set "j=Ms[i].t" assuming "Ms[0].t" is set.

```
for(j=Ms[i].t;dt*j <= Ms[i+1].t;j++)
```

"Accelerator restriction: size of the GPU copy of Y,X is unknown"

This is telling you that the compiler can not implicitly copy the X and Y arrays on the device.  In C/C++, unbounded pointers don't have sizes so the compiler can't tell how big these arrays are.  Often it can derive this information from the loop trip counts, but since the loop trip count is unknown (see above), it can't in this case.  To fix, you need to include a data directive on the "kernels" directive or add a data region to your code.  For example:

```
#pragma acc kernels copyout(X[0:size], Y[0:size])
```

or

```
 #pragma acc data copyout(X[0:size], Y[0:size])
 {
    ...
    #pragma acc kernels 
    ...
 }
```

Another thing to keep in mind is pointer aliasing.  In C/C++, pointers of the same type are allowed to point at the same object.  Hence, without additional information such as the "restrict" attribute, the "independent" clause, or the PGI compiler flag "-Msafeptr", the compiler must assume your pointers do point to the same object making the loop not parallelizable.

Comment: Hello, i change my code  and get errors, #pragma acc kernels copyin(TEMPX[1:k],TEMPY[1:k],TEMPT[1:k],MLX[1:k],MLY[1:k],w[1:k]) copyout(X[1:N],Y[1:N])
{
#pragma acc loop independent
    for (int i = 0;i < k; i++)
    {
        //#pragma acc loop independent
        for(j=i*(int)N/k;j*dt <= TEMPT[i+1];j++)
        {
            X[j] = MLX[i]*(1-w[j])+TEMPX[i+1]*w[j];
            Y[j] = MLY[i]*(1-w[j])+TEMPY[i+1]*w[j];
        }
    }
} and get this warning: Variable length arrays not yet supported in

Comment: /initialization double X[(int)N],Y[(int)N],w[(int)N],TEMPT[k],TEMPX[k],TEMPY[k];

Comment: Correct. We (PGI) don't currently support VLAs in device code.  Please make these variables pointers, and then dynamically allocate them.

Answer (score 1):

This would most likely go away by either adding loop independent to the inner loop as well or using the collapse clause to flatted the loop, applying independent to both. Might also go away if all of your arrays are passed in using `restrict`, but maybe not.